# Is there a way to define PyPI repos globally for Poetry?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

For example when you have 2 PyPI repos named X and Y here's how you currently have to do it with Poetry 1.4.2:

1. modify the local `pyproject.toml` file:

   - via shell commands `poetry source add --default X url_for_x` then `poetry source add --secondary Y url_for_y`
2. edit the poetry global config file `auth.toml` with:

   ```ini
   [certificates.X]
   cert = false

   [http-basic.X]
   username = USERNAME
   password = PASSWORD

   [certificates.Y]
   cert = false

   [http-basic.Y]
   username = USERNAME
   password = PASSWORD
   ```
3. modify global Poetry config file `config.toml` to add:

   ```ini
   [repositories.Y]
   url = "https://your/url/for/package/uploads/pypi"
   ```

If you have 10 Python wheels then you have to do the first step 10 times, which is frustrating. It is best to define it once instead of copy/paste everywhere, otherwise:

- If it changes you need to manually edit 10 times. Or write a script to sed the value for you.
- Every new Poetry project needs to do the extra `poetry source add` twice.

I know there is Poetry version 1.5 but I am using Poetry 1.4 because `poetry shell` errors out for when you have a Python 3.6 env.